# Deploy from gitlab to own server via GitLab CI and SSH

Tags: git, symfony, ssh, deployment, gitlab-ci

I've created a private repository (it's Symfony application) on GitLab and want to setup deployment through GitLab CI. At this moment I can work with git on the client side, that means I can pull & push etc. I've also setup gitlab-ci.yml in the repo so it runs defined stages when merged into master.

I have SSH keys set in GitLab in my account and on the server I generated it through freeSSHd. Runner is also set on server which runs on Windows. But now I don't know how to physically put the GitLab repo to the server and where to specify the path where the files should be put. I'm doing for the first time so I really struggle to really understand this whole process.

So the more detailed instructions the better for me.

Here is how my files looks like:

config.toml

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "drici-runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "dd3614ae2de286e8af45ef39297d2c"
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "admin"
    password = "admin"
    host = "**.***.***.***"
    port = "22"
    identity_file = "C:/Program Files (x86)/freeSSHd/RSAKey.cfg"
  [runners.cache]
```

gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: geertw/docker-php-ci:7.0

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script: echo "Running tests"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - composer build

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to staging server"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://*****.**
  only:
  - master
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when the runner is on the same machine where you want to deploy. you dont need git or ssh. just copy the files from your build directory (`.`) to your wanted target directory.

in general you dont should have a runner on a productive machine only for deployment. you should have a runner on a machine dedicated to deploying - but as you are on windows i'm not much of help.

Comment: Read about [deployer](https://deployer.org/), we're use it with the same environment. Also, deployer have prepared recipe for symfony3 and good documentation(but not full). However, I did not find any question in your text. I can recommend just read the docs of deployment instruments, select the one and use it.